# expo-av audio unloadAsync removeSubscription problem

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

The expo-av Playback class's unloadAsync method gives the following error: "TypeError: this._eventEmitter.removeSubscription is not a function" during unloadAsync function even though the unloading succeeds. Is there a way to avoid this error?

```
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';

...

useEffect(() => {
    let soundHandler;
    new Audio.Sound.createAsync(
        require('../assets/test.mp3'), {shouldPlay: true, isLooping: true}
    ).then(({sound, status}) => {
        soundHandler = sound;
    });

    return () =>  {
        soundHandler.unloadAsync().catch(err=>{
            console.log("Unload warning: " + err)
        });
    };
}, []);

...
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.